# Check URL syntax validity in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way in SQL Server (2005+) queries/procedures to check if a URL is syntactically correct? I don't want to do any network-related thing from within the SQL Server with that URL but I just need to know if it is valid from the aspect of syntax.

P.S.: I know there are ways to embed a CLR library and hence utilizing .net methods for these kinds of verifications but I want to check it without using those external stuff.

Comment: Why not check the URL before you insert it into your DB?

Comment: @tombom: A double check is required due to context of the problem.

Comment: There are ways to validate the URL by actually sending network traffic, using Object Automation extended stored procedures. If you are looking for just string validation, please post the elements you are looking for in the string

Comment: @Raj: I'm looking for regex-based validation, otherwise solutions like this are available (which involve things like reaching that url for being ensured about validity): http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/validate-a-url-from-sql-server.aspx